# How to close a Bootstrap Modal conditionally ERROR: $(...).modal

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, angular6, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to have a user submit a form in a Bootstrap Modal. If every field in the form is completed, the modal should disappear and information will be sent to the backend. If not every field is completed, I want an error message to display and the modal to remain open.

I'm working in angular 6 and it seems like a lot of people have had this issue, so I have tried some stuff from other stack exchange questions without success.

I changed my jQuery import from `import * as $ from 'jquery';` to `declare var $: any;`.

I tried disabling the button when the form is invalid and placing a `div` over it, so that when the `div` is clicked the error displays and when the button is clicked the form submits. This created problems with being able to access the button behind the `div`.

Based on something I read on **Github**, I changed my version of popper from 1.14 to 1.10.

My ideal solution is having the button function with a simple if else statement to give an error message, or submit the form and close the modal.

Script imports:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Modal html:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="domicilioModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="domicilioModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="domicilioModalLongTitle">Enviar a domicilio</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">                                                                               
                    <form #domicilioForm="ngForm">
                    </form>
                </div><br/>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="float-left btn-cbgb white" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn-cbgb blue float-right" (click)="enviarOrden('Enviar a domicilio', domicilioForm)">Enviar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
enviarOrden(metodo_de_completar, form) {
    if (!form.valid) { 
        this.alerts.error('Por favor complete campos requeridos');
    } else {
        console.log(metodo_de_completar, form.value);
        $('#domicilioModalCenter').modal('hide');
    }
}
```

I also tried:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {$('#domicilioModalCenter').modal('hide');});
```

with no success.

I keep getting the error `$(...).modal` is not a function. Really just trying to toggle the functionality of the **Enviar** button. Open to any and all ideas. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is just because of overlap of jquery. Try to remove jquery from script array in angular cli.json file.